# Sending a content to an email in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am following a tutorial and try to send something to an email in laravel. When I clicked the submit button, *an uncaught* appear at the browser console for a sec and then nothings happen. I want it to be like when I click the button, an email is sent to the user's email. I am wondering what I did wrong here ? The following are my code :

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\ForgotPasswordPDF as MailForgotPasswordPDF;

class ForgotPasswordPDF2 extends Controller
{
    public function sendPassword(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->email;
        $email = Str::lower($email);
        $user = User::findUserByEmail($email);

        Mail::to($email)->send(new MailForgotPasswordPDF);

        $result = [
            'message' => 'hantarpassword.success',
        ];
        return response()->json($result);
    }
}
```

Route

```
// Lupa kata laluan PDF
    Route::post('forgotpasswordpdf', [ForgotPasswordPDF2::class, 'cariemail'])->name('cari.email');
```

form

```
const submit = (e) => {
        post(route('cari.email'));
    }

<form onSubmit={submit}>
  <span className="flex items-center justify-center">
  <input type="hidden" value="akmal.adib@devwiz.my" name="email"/>
     <button type="submit">
         <RiLockPasswordLine
         className=" h-4 w-4"
         data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
         data-tooltip-content="Hantar Kata Laluan" 
         />
     </button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Without the error from the console, it is hard to know what the problem is.